# Rails: Displaying pages navigation inside application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to display a page navigation but Rails in addiction to page_title outputs all the record's informations inside brackets like this:

```
- About [#<Page id: 1, page_title: "About", page_content: "About page content", created_at: "2013-05-04 06:38:03", updated_at: "2013-05-04 06:38:03">] 
- Other page [#....etc...]
```

How I can fix this? Thx.

**application.html.erb**

```
<li>
    <%= @pages.each do |p| %>
        <%= link_to page_path(p.id) do %>
            <%= p.page_title %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>           
</li>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    before_filter :set_layout_variables

    def set_layout_variables
        @pages = Page.all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `=` in your line `<%= @pages.each do |p| %>`

It should be

```
<li>
    <% @pages.each do |p| %>
        <%= link_to page_path(p.id) do %>
            <%= p.page_title %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>           
</li>
```

`<%=` will output the result of the line (in your case, the loop), which displays the page record. That's why you see the record in your output.

Comment: Always hard to see the little buggy character :) please validate my answer

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, it says that I can accept an answer in 7 minutes. I will do it, for sure